# Use VBA to retrieve and call VBA code from a text file

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project to process some incoming Outlook messages using [rule-triggered](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) VBA code.

However, I don't want to have to manually update the code for each user's inbox any time the code needs to change. So my idea is to put a text file on a shared drive and have the VBA pull that text file down and treat it like code. Essentially, I want to use that text file like a little code library.

I was able to find [this link](https://gitsolutionsbd.com/how-to-create-your-own-vba-code-library-in-excel/) that has gotten me very close to my goal. However, I'm having a few issues with it.

Here is the code I put together. It is attached to the click event of a Rectangle shape I inserted into an Excel file. Eventually, I'll move this over to Outlook, but I'm just doing a basic test with Excel VBA first.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim enviro As String
    Dim myFile As String

    'Pull code "library" from text file on user's desktop
    'This will eventually be changed to reside on a shared drive
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    myFile = enviro & "\Desktop\hello_vba.txt"

    'If the "Library" module already exists, delete it
    For Each a In Modules
        If a.Name = "Library" Then
            a.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Add a new module
    Set m = Application.Modules.Add

    'Rename it to "Library"
    m.Name = "Library"

    'Insert the text from the other file to this new module
    m.InsertFile myFile

    'Call the hello() subroutine from the retrieved text file
    Library.Hello

Exit_Here:
'Cleanup code goes here
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Here
Exit Sub
```

And here is the content of the external text file named "hello_vba.txt":

```
Sub Hello()
        MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

The first time I run this, using the debugger I can see that it creates the new module and then gets to the line that says:

```
m.Name = "Library"
```

And then a window pops up in the debugger that says:

> Can't enter break mode at this time

When I click continue on that message, I get an

> Object Required

error message. If it run it again, then I get some more error messages but I do eventually get a successful "Hello" message box pop up.

I'm wondering if I may not have "Dim"ed the "a" or "m" variables properly or if there is a problem trying to pull in a text file and immediately treat it like code?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your new code, try using Application.Run instead of `Library.Hello`

It would be written:

```
Application.Run("Hello")
```

Does that work?

Comment: Yes! That fixed the primary issue. Thanks. I have a secondary issue when I run the program a second time. When it gets to the a.Delete line, I get a message in the main spreadsheet that says "Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion. To permanently delete the data, press Delete." Not sure how to bypass that.

Comment: Well, that was a small fix. I added "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" to the beginning of the subroutine and that fixed it. Thanks again!